# PHP / MySQL Checking data between tables with long query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is a more detailed question as my previous attempt wasn't clear enough. I'm new to MySQL and have no idea about the best way to do certain things. I'm building a voting application for images and am having trouble with some of the finer points of MySQL

My db

_votes

- id
- voter_id
- image_id

_images

- id
- file_name
- entrant_id
- approved

_users

- id
- ...

Basically I need to do the following:

1. tally up all votes that are approved
2. return the top 5 with the most votes
3. check if the user has voted on each of these 5 (return Boolean) from another table

I've tried variations of

```
SELECT i.id, i.file_name, i.total_votes
FROM _images i WHERE i.approved = 1 
CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) from _votes v WHERE v.image_id = i.id AND v.voter_id = ?) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END 'hasvoted'
ORDER BY i.total_votes DESC LIMIT ".($page*5).", 5
```

is that something I should try and do all in one query?

This query was working fine before I tried to add in the 'hasvoted' boolean:

```
SELECT id, file_name, total_votes FROM _images WHERE approved = 1 ORDER BY total_votes DESC LIMIT ".($page*5).", 5
```

At the moment I'm also storing the vote count in the _images table and I know this is wrong, but I have no idea about how to tally the votes by image_id and then order them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give this a shot to see if I understand your question:

```
SELECT i.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _votes WHERE i.id = image_id) AS total_votes, (SELECT count(*) from _votes where i.id = image_id and user_id = ?) as voted  FROM _images AS i WHERE i.approved = 1
```

Comment: What is the column definition on _image.approved?

Comment: actually, there was an error and realised that the fact I'm using mysqli prepared statements might matter:
:$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT i.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _votes WHERE i.id = image_id) AS total_votes, (SELECT count(*) from _votes where i.id = image_id and user_id = ?) as voted FROM _images AS i WHERE i.approved = 1");

[Thu Jun 09 16:00:27 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.113] PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in ...

Comment: I would suggest testing the query first in mysql directly to make sure its working.  The query does have a bind marker for user_id.

Comment: good idea. the binding is working fine, but I'll try directly

Comment: user_id should be voter_id and then I'm getting closer. voted is returning a number and not a boolean

Comment: In PHP, you can treat any non-zero number as true, and 0 as false. But if you need absolute types, you can wrap the sub query in an if statement.